# How to use all view and helper methods inside of Rails console for Rails 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`helper.method_name` worked in some version of Rails... are there ways that work in both Rails 2.2.2, 2.3.5, and 3.0.1?  (to use all view and helper methods)

Answer (score 96):

You can also try :

```
YourController.helpers.my_helper
```

for example :

```
> ApplicationController.helpers.content_tag(:div, "test")
=> "<div>test</div>"
```

This works with Rails 2, 3 and 4.1

Comment: How do I render a partial with this? Rails 4. `ApplicationController.helpers.render Post.last
NoMethodError: undefined method 'include?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: >MyController.helpers.my_method(arg1, arg2); This is what I am looking for.

Comment: In Rails 5+ I use only: helper.method_name(parameters)

Answer (score 62):

please try to this

```
rails console
helper.any_method_of_helper(pass_argument)
```

example

```
helper.number_to_currency('123.45')
```

Comment: This works. However there is an additional case wherein if you have defined your helper methods inside a file nested inside a module for e.g. `MyModule::ModuleSpecificViewHelper` (defined at `/app/helpers/my_module/module_specific_view_helper.rb`), then in rails console you should include that module first (if not already included) and then try `helper.your_method` and you should get it.

Comment: Work like a charm for Rails 4.2.11

Comment: And also like a charm in Rails 5.2!