# How to add commas to a large integer number and add zeros after first comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider  an integer number `@num = 27565`. I want to display it as `27,000`

I tried this in my rails console:

```
number_with_delimiter(12345678)   # => 12,345,678
```

But I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `number_with_delimiter' for main:Object
```

Some of the examples are:

```
12345678   # => 12,000,000
27565   # => 27,000
```

**UPDATE**

---

The `NoMethodError` was fixed by following:

[How to use all view and helper methods inside of Rails console for Rails 2.x and 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112050/how-to-use-all-view-and-helper-methods-inside-of-rails-console-for-rails-2-x-and)

But my second question, i.e how to add zeros after first comma, was not answered.

Comment: it is better to create one question … per question :)

Comment: So, should I create another question? :/

Comment: you can just use a decimal instead of an integer

Comment: Just for fun...  
n = (@num.to_s.length - 1)/3.0;
r = (@num[0...-(n.to_i*3)] + (",000" * n.to_i) ).to_i